# iOS accessibility fields grouped by View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uiaccessibility

As I understand it the accessibility tool on iOS reads top down and left to right.  Is there a way to group by view so that two views next to each other at equal height (one on the right and one on the left) will not have their respective elements read together (right left, right left) but rather all the right view's elements followed by the left view's elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **UIAccessibilityContainer** protocol and especially the **shouldGroupAccessibilityElement** instance property may help you grouping all the accessible elements to be read out by VoiceOver in a specific order.

I suggest to take a look at this [good example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#reading-order) including {code snippet *(ObjC;Swift)* + illustration} that highlights the way to spell out a numeric keypad following a predetermined sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good, but to save the next person more reading here's what you can do:

```
func setAccessibility() {
  /// groups all elements into a single accessibility element. 
  /// The order isn't important for screen reader.
  accessibilityElements = [rightLabel, leftLabel]

  /// required 
  isAccessibilityElement = true
    
  /// grouping does not auto generate accessibilityLabel content,
  /// so you can setup the text as you like.
  let rightText = rightLabel.text ?? ""
  let leftText = leftLabel.text ?? ""
  accessibilityLabel = "\(rightText), \(leftText)"
}
```

The order of the array of elements isn't really important to a screen reader as the label still needs to be constructed separately. There may be other purposes for keeping the order though.